Page not found error using Django urlconfig
I'm having trouble mapping a page to another page in Django. The app name is Task, and the HTML files are inside templates\tasks file. The files exist, it's just Django can't find them for some reason! When I just write the path in the browser (http://127.0.0.1:8000/Task/add), the pages appear, but when I put the path in the HTML, it gives me a page not found error.
Page picture: Page not found error
The settings of the main app.
settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'Home',
    'Date',
    'Task',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

The URLs of the created apps
urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('Home/', include('Home.urls')),
    path('Date/', include('Date.urls')),
    path('Task/', include('Task.urls'))
]

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

taskslist = ["add", "edit", "delete"]
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, "tasks/index.html", {
        "taskslist": taskslist
    })

def add(request):
    return render(request, "tasks/add.html")

ursl.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "Task"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("add", views.add, name="add")
]

index.html
{% extends "tasks/layout.html" %} {% block body%}

<h1>Tasks</h1>

<ul>
  {% for t in taskslist %}
  <li><a href="{ url '{{t}}'}">{{t}}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<!-- This part didn't work -->
<a href="{% url 'Task:add' %}">Add a task!</a>
<a href="add.html">Add a task!</a>

{% endblock %}

add.html
{% extends "tasks/layout.html" %} {% block body%}

<h1>Add Task</h1>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="task" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<!-- This line didn't work -->
<a href="{% url 'Task:index' %}">View Tasks</a>{% endblock %}
<a href="index.html">View Tasks</a>

I have read many solutions about the same issues but none solved mine

What do you have in Task/apps.py file?

@mx0 the default from django.apps import AppConfig
class TaskConfig(AppConfig):
default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
name = 'Task'

Have you tried turning off and on the server?
If you see a page not found error, it may be that url is not applied.
When I tested other parts in my environment, there was no problem.
Can you post a detailed error log in the question body?

@Antoliny I did try yes and it's still not working. I added a screenshot of the error up in the top of the question body.

When I see the error image, there seems to be no problem with the add path, but the template tag used in the li-tag url on the index page seems to be wrong.
index.html
<ul>
  {% for name, path in taskslist.items %}
  <li><a href="{ url '{{t}}'}">{{name}}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

The indentation is not correct and the variable is incorrectly used within the template tag, so click the button on the index page causes the same error as the questioner.
index.html
<h1>Tasks</h1>
<ul>
  {% for name, path in taskslist.items %}
    <li><a href="{% url path %}">{{name}}</a></li>
    <!-- <li><a href="{ url '{{t}}'}">{{name}}</a></li> -->
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
<!-- This part didn't work -->
<a href="{% url 'Task:add' %}">Add a task!</a>
<a href="add.html">Add a task!</a>

views.py
taskslist = {"add": "Task:add"}
...

I changed the data type to pass to the template to the dictionary and also modified the template tag.
I excluded edit, delete because it's not in url yet. You can add it later.
